# How to match this kind of color name with Perl regex in vim?

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my darkerdesert.vim:

```
hi Cursor       guibg=#b3b3df   guifg=grey30    gui=bold
hi VertSplit    guibg=#505050   guifg=grey50    gui=none
hi Folded       guibg=#252525   guifg=gold3
hi FoldColumn   guibg=#252525   guifg=gold3
hi IncSearch    guifg=slategrey dark guibg=ghost white
hi LineNr       guifg=grey30
hi ModeMsg      guifg=goldenrod3
hi MoreMsg      guifg=SeaGreen Dark
hi NonText      guifg=LightBlue guibg=#252525
hi Question     guifg=#28a45c
```

I need to extract the color that names with English such as "LightBlue","slategrey dark ".
My solution is below:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    print $1,"\n" while /(?:[bf]g\=\K(?!\#)(.*)(?=gui))/g;
}
```

With the pattern `/[bf]g\=\K(?!\#)(.*)(?=gui)/` ,I can get the items between `gui[bf]g=` only.
So my question is : How to match all the English color names?(goldenrod3,SeaGreen....etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the regex `/gui[fb]g=([^#]+?)\s+(?=\w+=|\z)/g`.

Here is some sample code to demonstrate it working with your own data.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  print join ', ', map qq("$_"), /gui[fb]g=([^#]+?)\s+(?=\w+=|\z)/g;
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
hi Cursor       guibg=#b3b3df   guifg=grey30    gui=bold
hi VertSplit    guibg=#505050   guifg=grey50    gui=none
hi Folded       guibg=#252525   guifg=gold3
hi FoldColumn   guibg=#252525   guifg=gold3
hi IncSearch    guifg=slategrey dark guibg=ghost white
hi LineNr       guifg=grey30
hi ModeMsg      guifg=goldenrod3
hi MoreMsg      guifg=SeaGreen Dark
hi NonText      guifg=LightBlue guibg=#252525
hi Question     guifg=#28a45c
```

**output**

```
"grey30"
"grey50"
"gold3"
"gold3"
"slategrey dark", "ghost white"
"grey30"
"goldenrod3"
"SeaGreen Dark"
"LightBlue"
```

Answer (score 1):

A more obvious, but not necessary better solution:

```
use strict;

my @c;  # colors
my @m;  # matches

while ( <DATA> ) {
  @m = /guifg=([\w ]+?) *($|gui)/;  # trying to extract the FG color, if exists
  push(@c, $m[0]) if $m[0];
  @m = /guibg=([\w ]+?) *($|gui)/;  # trying to extract the BG color, if exists
  push(@c, $m[0]) if $m[0];
}

map { print $_, "\n", } @c;  # all color names are in @c, do whatever you want with them
```

Comment: thank you ~~ people in stackoverflow are really warm-hearted.

Comment: Why have two lines when `[fb]` can replace one of them? And why on earth do you insert a print in a map-statement? `use v5.10; say for @c;`, or `print "$_\n" for @c;"

Comment: @TLP well, I'm still living in the Perl 5.8 universe, so I'm not too familiar with all these new features ... yes, I know, a long time passed and I should be, but ... :) ; about 2 lines: I just wrote it as simple as possible, a single regex would be more sophisticated (or probably not, I was not searching for the most optimal answer, just one to be easy to read and understand)

Comment: @TLP: a working program requires more than just using `[fb]` and knocking out one of the lines. It is a valid technique to pull out the bg and fg colours separately. I can't say the same for `map` in void context though - that is a nasty habit.

Comment: @Borodin I think I said once that one gets the same result by using `grep`, but that it better shows the full extent of one's madness. Also, you already wrote the working program: I am just commenting ArtM's code.